# Extend login system without storing user credentials on server or use common providers

Tags: asp.net-mvc, email, azure, authentication, registration

I'm looking for advice on how I should handle the registration of my current system.
In my current solution, users must sign in with Google, Yahoo or Live through Access Controll Service (ACS). When the users are logged in, they are redirected to the my website where they can complete the registration. I want to extend the system so that users can login with their e-mail without the need to fasten/bind their business email to a provider (Gmail yahoo etc.).

But since the system should not handle sensitive information, I wonder if there's any company that can do it for you. (As a common login system but the company handles user credentials)

So in short: Is there any solution for the user to login with there buissness email without binding it to Google, Live, Yahoo? (when I dont want to handle the user credentials on my server)